# QUEST Staircase Resolution and Accuracy

Tags: methodology, vision, psychophysics, task-analysis

I am flickering letters on and off to participants, controlled by a flicker rate which I am restricting to **integer values**.

If I want to implement a **QUEST staircase** to determine the **final threshold estimate** of the flicker rate, is it possible for the threshold estimate to be of a **higher resolution** than the grain size of 1 that I have chosen? Phrased differently, **how precise will the estimate be**? QUEST would be more efficient than method of constant stimuli; however, I do not want to use QUEST if in exchange I have to sacrifice the accuracy of the final threshold.